# Error-Unable to open BCP host file data, while executing BCP command

Tags: sql-server-2008, file, bcp

I'm trying to copy data from a '.dat' file to a table in sql server
I'm getting this error while executing the following commands:

```
declare @cmd varchar(100)
set @cmd = 'bcp dBFCLogging.dbo.TempBFCLogs in ' + '''D:\WorkArea\data.dat''' + ' -c -T'
exec xp_cmdshell @cmd
```

The exact error message:

```
SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]Unable to open BCP host data-file
NULL
```

I ran a print command and checked the cmd variable, and that looks okay.

```
bcp dBFCLogging.dbo.TempBFCLogs in 'D:\WorkArea\data.dat' -c -T
```

I'm running this command on a DB server, so I have this file under the correct path on that DB server. I had read that there could be permission issues. So, I have enabled the user 'Everyone' to have Read/Execute access on that folder structure and also the file, but it still throws this error while execution.
Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Change "**D:\WorkArea\data.dat**" to `"D:\\WorkArea\\data.dat"`

Comment: umm, what's the difference?

Comment: "\" gets treated as escape characters, while "\\" negates the effect and gets treated as single slash(/).

Comment: @karank - SO is removing the second slash in the answer when it displays.  I just changed the formatting so it shows up properly now.

Answer (score 0):

If you put quotes around a file name they need to be double quotes, not single quotes. Your command should be:

```
declare @cmd varchar(100);
set @cmd = 'bcp dBFCLogging.dbo.TempBFCLogs in "D:\WorkArea\data.dat" -c -T';
exec xp_cmdshell @cmd;
```

There may be additional problems depending on the way data is formatted in the data file. In some cases you need to describe this in a format file and refer to this format file in your BCP command using the `-f` option.